# Как сделать std::bind для шаблонной функции с шаблонным параметром?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как сделать `std::bind` для шаблонной функции с шаблонным параметром?
Просто `std::bind(&foo, arg)` не работает, потому что тип `foo` не известен. Пока что в лоб сделал так `std::bind(&foo<decltype(arg)>,arg)`, но может быть есть вариант лучше?

Comment: видели, что многие какую то функцию назывют  так(не я) и везде пишете foo  foo foo. Вы думаете, что foo это какая то определенная стандартная функция? А если нет, то  хотябы покажите ее обьявление

Comment: @ARHovsepyan https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/555385/320823

Comment: дело в том, что вы не понели смысль  моего комментария.  Вам нужно правильно подать вопрос, а  ваш foo  неизвестно что в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan шаблонная функция с шаблонным параметром, написано же

Comment: шаблонная функция  не известна, если не известны количество и типы аргументов и тип возвращаемого значения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Напрямую выполнить `std::bind` можно только так, как сделали вы (или эквивалентными способами), т.е. путем выбора конкретной специализации функции еще до выполнения `std::bind`.
2. Однако также этот вопрос можно решить через промежуточную variadic template функцию

   ```
   #include <functional>
   #include <iostream>

   template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
   void foo(A a, B b, C c)
   {
     std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
   }

   template<typename ...T>
   auto my_bind(void (*f)(T ...), T ...args) 
   {
     return std::bind(f, args...);
   }

   int main()
   {
     auto bound_foo = my_bind(foo, 1, 2.0, "Hello");
     bound_foo();
   }
   ```

   Вот как только развить это до использования `std::placeholders`, т.е. как предоставить возможность оставить несвязанные параметры - не скажу навскидку.
3. Ну и, конечно, можно предложить вообще отказаться от использования `std::bind` и вместо него использовать лямбды

   ```
   auto bound_foo = []() { return foo(arg); };
   ```

   С практической точки зрения это, наверное, самый правильный подход.